How to start Android and bypass the SIM PIN?
How to start Android and bypass the SIM PIN?
I'm asking myself why it is not possible to start/boot Android without entering the PIN for the SIM card.
The smartphone is a computer, with it's own authorization mechanism (device pin, finger print, ...) that I could easily use without access to the SIM and therefore the mobile network. (It is not about the screen lock pin).
Why does Android not allow to start without this SIM card PIN and later enter the PIN?
(E.g when I looked it up in my password manager in the phone)?
I'm using a Google Pixel 4a - Android 13 (not rooted).
I've not found a way in the settings about this.
Is there any way (removing the SIM is not a real solution)?
To add more context / explenation:

The smartphone is protected with the device PIN (or finger print, ...). This is required on "login" after a reboot or to remove the screen lock.
The SIM card is protected with the SIM PIN. This pin is required when the SIM functions are accessed - usually the smartphone keeps its authenticated access to the SIM functions once accessed for the first time as long as it is running. (This is not a permanent unlocking of the SIM, I don't know if this is even possible)
The problem is that on startup/boot of Android is accessing the SIM card forcing to enter the SIM PIN. This can not be skipped. This shall not be needed, as the Smartphone would work fine without the SIM as well (e.g. if physically removed).


Check with your carrier on how to unlock the SIM... If your SIM is unlocked you don't need to enter the SIM PIN again//SIM check is not mandatory as far as Android is concerned

The question is good, but I fear you won't get an answer because why Android does not allow to skip SIM PIN entering is most likely only know to the developer who coded it in the beginning. My guess is the behavior was talken over from the cellular phones of the pre-smartphone era without thinking it over.

@Robert I am surprised. I've been using the same SIM for about 20 years, when smartphones weren't around and I never had to enter the SIM PIN//At least twice I had to change the physical SIM due to damage while retaining the number, yet never entered the code//Haven't seen anybody needing to do that either (work or family)... Hence my comment

@beeshyams: I'm not sure if I do understand - but if the SIM gets unlocked like that, this looks just like a security issue (consider loosing it). Might be a solution to the question I have, but one that should not be considered form my point of view.

It may be a silly question. We are talking about the SIM pin and not the Phone lock Pin?

@PaulEdison :I understand that SIM PIN gives you an extra layer of protection both for your device and the SIM itself but then you pay the price in terms of ease of login, which is what your question is about

@RohitGupta: The question is basically about "Why does Android access the SIM (requiring the SIM PIN) while startup and not only the device PIN".

@beeshyams: I disagree. On startup of my mobile computer, also known as Android smartphone, does not need to access the SIM card. Only on accessing the SIM card, the SIM PIN is needed. On Startup of the smartphone only the device PIN shall be required (as this is what I do intentionally access). The SIM PIN does add NO layer of security to the smartphone (as it can be removed - physically). If I would be able to (I don't know if there is a way to) permanently unlock the SIM card, this would pose a risk on the SIM (what is as well not wanted) not on the smartphone.

There's an old Q&A Access phone without SIM PIN that suggested turning on Airplane mode, though I can't say for modern phones.

I've been using same phone no for about 20 years, whenever I booted cell phone with SIM inserted I had to enter the SIM pin. disabling SIM pin would allow thief to make phone calls on my bill, that's why I leave it enabled. nevertheless I have had smartphones that were able to circumvent SIM pin when airplane mode was enabled. as soon as I disabled flight mode the SIM pin was asked and there was no way to skip
